# My composer project's class won't load

Tags: php, function, class, composer-php, packagist

I have a Packagist package for composer, [lwilson/onepage](https://packagist.org/packages/lwilson/onepage), with one PHP file.  The file has one class, which contains one function.  I have installed the package on my Web server, and I have a PHP file which is supposed to use it.  I know that the composer autoloader is included properly, since I could use other composer libraries installed on the server.  I get the following result:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OnePage\OnePage' not found in /home/photox952/public_html/onepage/test_onepage.php on line 6
```

`test_onpepage.php` (the file that uses the class):

```html
<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use OnePage\OnePage;

file_put_contents("index.php",OnePage::OnePage(json_decode(file_get_contents("cfg.json")),__DIR__));
?>
```

`compiler.php` (the file in the package):

```html
<?php
namespace OnePage;

// This is licenced under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE.  More info at: https://github.com/LeoWilson-XnD/lwilson_onepage/blob/master/LICENSE

class OnePage{
 public static function OnePage($cfg,$dir){
  $tmplt_u = "<?php if(\$_REQUEST['type']==\"{TYPE}\"&&\$_REQUEST['src']==\"{SRC}\"){header(\"Content-Type: {CT}\"); ?>{DATA}<?php } ?>";
  $tmplt_c = "<?php if(\$_REQUEST['all']==\"{TYPE}\"){header(\"Content-Type: {CT}\"); ?>{DATA}<?php } ?>";
  $res = "<?php /* This code is generated by the OnePage tool.  Find out more here: https://github.com/LeoWilson-XnD/lwilson_onepage */ ?>";
  $dir.=$cfg['dir'];
  if($cfg['v']==1){
   foreach($cfg['unique'] as $ka => $va){
    foreach($cfg[$ka] as $kb => $vb){
     $u = $tmplt_u;
     $u=str_replace("{TYPE}",explode("/",$ka)[1],$u);$u=str_replace("{SRC}",$kb,$u);$u=str_replace("{CT}",$ka,$u);$u=str_replace("{DATA}",file_get_contents($dir.$vb),$u);
     $res.=$u;
    }
   }
   foreach($cfg['combine'] as $ka => $va){
    $ds = "";
    foreach($cfg[$ka] as $kb => $vb){
     $ds.=file_get_contents($dir.$vb);
    }
    $u = $tmplt_c;
    $u=str_replace("{TYPE}",explode("/",$ka)[1],$u);$u=str_replace("{CT}",$ka,$u);$u=str_replace("{DATA}",file_get_contents($dir.$vb),$u);
    $res.=$u;
   }
   foreach($cfg['links'] as $key => $val){
    $res = str_replace($val,$key,$res);
   }
  }
  return $res;
 }
}
?>
```

`composer.json` (the package's `composer.json` file):

```html
{
    "name": "lwilson/onepage",
    "description": "This allows users to compile websites easily into one PHP file.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Leo Wilson",
            "email": "lwilson@xlww.net",
   "homepage": "https://xlww.net/",
   "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
 "version": "v1.0.0",
 "homepage": "https://github.com/LeoWilson-XnD/lwilson_onepage",
 "licence":"GPL-3.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the autoload wrong in composer. Try to create a folder named `OnePage` and put the file with the class in it. It must be named `OnePage.php`

Then set autoload like this

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "OnePage\\": "OnePage"
    }
  }
```

then run `composer update` from the shell. Then try running your php file again.

The `OnePage.php` file should be in folder `/home/photox952/public_html/onepage/OnePage`